# Regex to match _ or end of string

Tags: regex, matlab, match

I'm working with MATLAB's `regexp()` and I'm trying to find a regular expression that would match only file names containing `Cyto` but not `CytoBlue`. My problem is that the file names look either like `Texture_Variance_Cyto_4_90` and `Texture_Variance_CytoBlue_4_90`, or `HIST_9BinsHistBin7_Cyto` and `HIST_9BinsHistBin7_CytoBlue`.

If I just try to match `Cyto`, I also capture all the files containing `CytoBlue`. If I try to match `Cyto_`, I miss the file names where `Cyto` is the last element. I guess I'd need something that says "match either _ or the end of the string". I tried `Cyto[_\Z]` but that does not work, I again miss all the elements that ends with `Cyto`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Cyto(?=$|_)
```

This matches `Cyto`, followed by (`"(?=...)"`) the end of the string (`"$"`) or `_`. Note that the underscore is not returned as part of the match.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex: `Cyto(_.*?(?= ))?\b`

Comment: According to the docs, MATLAB uses `\<` and `\>` for word boundaries, not `\b`.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB supports positive and negative lookaheads, so this this should work:

```
Cytp(?!Blue)
```

...meaning "Cyto" not followed by "Blue".