# MySQL REGEXP Match / or End of Field

Tags: mysql, regex

I've got a load of paths in a MySQL Database (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) and the user chooses a selection of paths, I want to select all those paths and those below, but I've hit an issue.

Say the user wants "/root/K" I need to do a select for:

```
a. /root/K%
b. /root/K
```

How can I get the REGEXP to match the end of a field or a / ?

I've tried the following:

original query:

```
where path REGEXP ('/root/K/|/root/J/J/')  # this works but doesn't show the items in that path, only ones below

where path REGEXP '/root/K[/\z]' # does the same as above
where path REGEXP '/root/K(?=/|$)'   # Get error 1139, repetition-operator invalid
```

I've also tried: [Regex to match _ or end of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810229/regex-to-match-or-end-of-string) but that gives error 1139

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Done, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for lookarounds, not `\z` anchor in MySQL regex. You may use a normal capturing group:

```
WHERE path REGEXP '/root/K(/|$)'
```

It will match

- `/root/K` - literal char sequence
- `(/|$)` - either `/` or end of entry.